# Async InputQuery doesn't handle Cancel button

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

I'm using a simple call to `TDialogServiceAsync.InputQuery()` with a single input.  It just ignores both the `Cancel` button and the window's `X` close button.

But the `Ok` button works fine.

This is my code:

```
uses
  FMX.DialogService.Async;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TDialogServiceAsync.InputQuery('Title',
   ['Insert value'], ['bla bla'],
  procedure(const AResult: TModalResult; const AValues: array of string)
  begin
    if Aresult = mrOk then
      ShowMessage('Ok!');

    if Aresult = mrCancel then
      ShowMessage('Cancel!'); // this is never called
  end);
end;
```

If I press `Cancel`, the InputQuery window doesn't close, and my callback procedure is not called.

How I can make the InputQuery form close when pressing the `Cancel` button?

I'm using RADStudio 10.1 Berlin.

---

Edit:

I made a few tests:

1. On Windows 32 bit cancel button **DOES NOT** works
2. On Windows 64 bit cancel button **DOES NOT** works
3. On iOS 64 bit cancel button **works correctly**
4. On Android 32 bit cancel button **works correctly**

Comment: What OS are you targeting?

Comment: I have this issue with Win32 and Win64. I just tried on iOS64 and it works

Comment: Welcome to the weird and wonderful world of FMX

Comment: Even if the docs says that there is only a input field and a ok button ( http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FMX.Platform.IFMXDialogServiceAsync.InputQueryAsync ) the form contains also a Cancel button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug.  There are already bug reports for this issue in Embarcadero's [Quality Portal](http://quality.embarcadero.com):

[RSP-16148 TDialogService.InputQuery() - Cancel button doesn't work](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16148)

[RSP-16670 Problem of TDialogService.InputQuery dialog box](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16670).

The latter ticket provides a fix to `FMX.DialogHelper.pas`:

> open
>
> ```
> FMX.DialogHelper.pas
> ```
>
> find
>
> ```
> class function TDialogBuilder.InputQuery(const ACaption: string; const APrompts: array of string;
> ```
>
> find
>
> ```
> Button := CreateButton(LForm, BorderSize, WorkArea, Layout, SMsgDlgCancel, mrCancel, LForm.ButtonOnClick);
> ```
>
> after this line, add
>
> ```
> //fix or add by flyign wang.
> Button.Cancel := True;
> LForm.FCanCancel := True;
> ```

Comment: With this fix Cancel button works ok, but one cannot close the dialog window by mouse [x], and after pressing ESC button on the keyboard extra pointer error appears. I added: LForm.ModalResult:=mrCancel; below LForm.FCanCancel :=True and commented out Close in TDialogForm.FormKeyDown. Now everything works fine in Windows. I will check mobile platforms later.